# Get the HTML source code of a web page on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building an application and I need to get the html code source of a web page in order to parse it (this web page is not on my server).

I'm coding in Javascript and I can't find a way to do it, I know there is a way to do it in Python (with requests library) and I want basicaly the same thing in Javascript.

Does someone know how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Just google for it: https://www.google.com/search?q=web+scraping+javascript

Comment: `document.documentElement.outerHTML`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```